# What are consequences of switching from 32 bit to 64 bit VM?

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine

I am wondering what are the possible pros and cons of switching from 32 bit to 64 bit VM. Most of answers I encountered suggest that with VM you don't need to worry about switch and you get extra addressable memory, but I am afraid that there is more to the problem.

Here is what I came up with:

**Pros:**

- substantially more addressable memory

**Cons:**

- whatever uses pointers under the hood will double up the memory usage - I know VMs do optimisations in order to avoid this problem, but I guess it's safe to assume that same logic under 64bit VM will potentially take more memory
- all deterministic outputs relying on memory hashes are likely to change

Anything more?

I am happy to take concrete example like JVM.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about the deterministic part because this is usually handled under the hood.  Yes, a 64 bit JVM may have a higher baseline footprint, but it also means you have more addressable memory.  If your program is crashing on a 32 bit JVM due to lack of memory, then what options do you really have?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are definitely right about that no-choice situation. But taking it from the other end: if your application does just fine under 32bit VM I guess you have valid reason not to go 64bit if you don't need extra memory.

Comment: Well, you may not have a valid reason now but you might anticipate such a need in the future.